# Timeouting rest request in processing

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is the code I have:

```
  return this.myService.getSomeThing()

    .then(someData => {
                return this.myService.getAll(someData.id)
                });
            }).then(response => { 
                // do something;
           })
```

How can I call `timeout` on `getAll` and `getSomeThing` ?
I am a newbie at angular, but in the case of a timeout I need to reroute to some other view (another html template).

Comment: Are these service $http services? In such a case you have set config.timeout on your calls to abort http requests

Answer (score 1):

I think `Promise.race` would work well here.  Something along the lines of (I haven't tested it, this is just an idea).

```
Promise.race([
    this.myService.getSomeThing()
        .then(someData => this.myService.getAll(someData.id)),
    new Promise( (y, n) => setTimeout( () => y('Timeout fired before completion of Service call'), 1000)
]).then( (resp) => console.log(resp));
```

the idea here is to wait 1000ms.  If the `service calls` complete before then the last `.then` will display their result, otherwise timeout message will show.